# apt-get update fails on debian squeeze with "File not found"

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I'm trying to update my old server running Debian Squeeze. apt-get update fails. The output is here:

```
Ign file: debs/ Release.gpg
Ign file:/root/ debs/ Translation-en                                                                 
Ign file:/root/ debs/ Translation-en_US                                                              
Ign file: debs/ Release                                                                              
Ign file: debs/ Sources                                                                              
Ign file: debs/ Packages                                                                             
Ign file: debs/ Sources                                                                              
Ign file: debs/ Packages                                                                             
Err file: debs/ Sources                                                                              
  File not found
Err file: debs/ Packages                                                                             
  File not found
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts Release.gpg                                                  
Get:1 ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/contrib Translation-en                             
Ign ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/contrib Translation-en                               
Get:2 ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/contrib Translation-en_US                          
Ign ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/contrib Translation-en_US                            
Get:3 ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/main Translation-en                                
Ign ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/main Translation-en                                  
Get:4 ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/main Translation-en_US                             
Ign ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/main Translation-en_US                 
Get:5 ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/non-free Translation-en              
Hit http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports Release.gpg                       
Hit http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/non-free Translation-en
Get:6 ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts/non-free Translation-en_US             
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts Release                                        
Hit http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports Release                           
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg                          
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts/main Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release 
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts/non-free Sources/DiffIndex
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts/contrib Sources
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://backports.debian.org squeeze-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts/non-free i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org squeeze-lts/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free i386 Packages
W: Failed to fetch file:/root/debs/Sources.gz  File not found

W: Failed to fetch file:/root/debs/Packages.gz  File not found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The contents of my sources.list are here:

```
# local packages
deb file:/root debs/
deb-src file:/root debs/

# the basic archive
deb ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts main non-free contrib
deb-src ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts main non-free contrib


# the security patches
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

What I've tried so far is to change the two first entries in sources.list from squeeze to squeeze-lts since just squeeze doesn't seem to exist in the repository anymore.

I know Squeeze is not officially supported anymore and I plan to upgrade sometimes in near future, but I want to get the current installation to a "clean" and up-to-date state first.

Comment: Please put essential information into your question and do not use external paste or file hosters, unless necessary. Linked information tends to get lost over time (e.g. on your pastebin after 29 days).

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought this would be more convenient than filling the post with the logs. Thank you for editing my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sources.list references two `file` sources:

```
deb file:/root debs/
deb-src file:/root debs/
```

These lines expect a local Debian distribution under the `/root/` directory (with a subdirectory `/root/debs/`). Apparently, the files from there are not available any more.

Unless you were maintaining a special repository for your own packages locally, you could comment or even delete those two lines without problems. An `apt-get dist-upgrade` should work, nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to get rid of the errors in apt-get update.