# Can't find source package with apt-get source on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, apt, source

I have an old server running Debian Squeeze. I'm trying to download the source of some package so that I can patch it manually. However, `apt-get source` fails for every package I try. An example:

```
root@xxxx:/home/myhomedir# apt-get source emacs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Ignore unavailable target release 'stable' of package 'emacs'
E: Unable to find a source package for
```

The same error repeats for every other source package I try. Installing a package with the same name works, however (for example `apt-get install emacs`). Here are the contents of my `sources.list`:

```
# the basic archive
deb ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts main non-free contrib
deb-src ftp://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts main non-free contrib

# the security patches
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

I initially thought it was because of errors I got from `apt-get update` (see my previous question at [apt-get update fails on debian squeeze with "File not found"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268139/apt-get-update-fails-on-debian-squeeze-with-file-not-found)), but this is now fixed and I still can't download sources.

Comment: This isn't a proper solution, but it would help point in the right direction: does `apt-get source emacs23/squeeze-lts` work? Could you [edit] your question to add the contents of `/etc/apt/preferences`?

Comment: This does not work either. I don't have file /etc/apt/preferences. I have a folder named /etc/apt/preferences.d but it's empty. However, I have a file named apt-file.conf and folder apt.conf.d/ that has several files in it. apt.conf.d/70debconf has this line that might be relevant: APT::Default-Release "stable";

Comment: Note: don't run `apt-get source` as root. It's not necessary, and doing things as root unnecessarily is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `APT::Default-Release "stable";` line in your configuration is pinning you to `stable` which none of your `deb` or `deb-src` lines provide (`stable` is now `jessie`). To be able to use `apt-get source` without upgrading your whole distribution, you should either comment the line or change `stable` to `squeeze-lts`.

Note that you don't need to be `root` to run `apt-get source`, you can run it as a standard user.

Also, as [garethTheRed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29406/gareththered) points out, Squeeze is no longer supported (which, importantly, means that it no longer receives security updates). Not only that, but [Squeeze LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using) itself is no longer supported either, so you should really migrate to Wheezy LTS or Jessie sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thank you! This worked... sort of. I can now download the sources, but it seems that I can't build them. Some of the build dependencies (drac-dev for example) don't seem to exist at all in the repository, which is weird.

Comment: That's probably because Squeeze has been archived, so you need to point plain `squeeze` URIs in your `apt` configuration to http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/ (`deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main non-free contrib`).

Answer (score 8):

Debian Squeeze is [end of life](https://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/).

To continue to use unsupported packages you'll need to point `apt-get` to a different repository.

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, comment out all the lines with a preceding `#`  and add the following line:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze contrib main non-free
```

This will allow you access to the last released version of Squeeze from the Debian archive site.

Comment: I tried this (and also added the same line with deb-src instead of deb). Still the same error. Also, the repositories I had before seem to still work. I can even go to the address of the repository in my browser and check that the packages indeed are still available.

Comment: Changing the sources.list and commenting out the old sources as suggested above, in Jan 2020 enabled me to complete an upgrade from Lenny to Squeeze (5.0 to 6.0), so thanks :-)